# Execute Overriden method when Base Class is executed - Salesforce Apex

Tags: apex, polymorphism

I have the following scenario, where i have overriden the base class method. When i am testing it, the parent class's Initial code is what gets executed. What should be done to get the overriden code executed?

```
public virtual class Parent{

  public void execute(Map<Id,Account> newAcntMap){
    method1(Map<Id,Account> newAcntMap);
 }

  public virtual void method1(Map<Id,Account> newAcntMap){
     //Initial Code
  }
  
}

public class Child extends Parent{
  public override void MethodName(Map<Id,Account> newAcntMap){
    //overriden code
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: The parent class's execute method is called from another class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (maybe) have a typo in your code? If the method name matches correct, it should work just fine, even if you only have a reference to the parent class. Here's a quick copy-paste example for you:

```
public class q342183 {
    virtual class V1 {
        public void demo() {
            method1();
        }
        public virtual void method1() {
            System.debug('V1');
        }
    }
    class V2 extends V1 {
        public override void method1() {
            System.debug('V2');
        }
    }
    public static void demo() {
        V1 x = new V2();
        x.demo();
    }   
}
```

And when you run it from Execute Anonymous:

```
q342183.demo();
```

You should get:

```
07:38:03.1 (21563652)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[12]|System.debug(ANY)
07:38:03.1 (21615839)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|V2
07:38:03.1 (21637570)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[12]|System.debug(ANY)
```

Make sure you're actually creating a Child, and not a Parent. Try this:

```
System.assert(((Object)myChildVar) instanceOf Child);
```

If it fails, that means you don't have a Child, but something else.